# Can't Access Data in S3 with Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have been using Javascript for a few months and my code runs well in local, but I have always the same problem in a Lambda function.

I cant access any data with `s3.getObject`.

This is a simple example code that doesn't run in Lambda:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.myHandler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Retrieve the object
    s3.getObject({
        Bucket: 'XXXXXX',
        Key: 'YYYYY'
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("data");
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because your function is being terminated before your callback is executed, since your `s3.getObject()` call is asynchronous under the hood.

In order to get data from AWS Lambda, you'll have to return your value like this:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.myHandler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Retrieve the object
    s3.getObject({
        Bucket: 'XXXXXX',
        Key: 'YYYYY'
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err)
        } else {
            callback(null, {statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(data) })
        }
    });
};
```

I suggest you use Node 8 though, so you can easily use [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await).

Your code would then look like this:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.myHandler = async (event) => {
  const data = await s3.getObject({
    Bucket: 'XXXXXX',
    Key: 'YYYYY'
  }).promise();

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }
};
```

Another problem in your code is that you always print `"data"` instead of `data`, so a String is printed instead of the data itself.

Comment: Your first example won't work. The return of status code and data is from within the getObject callback function. It should invoke the myHandler callback instead.

Comment: That's correct. Missed it. Edited accordingly. Thanks for bringing it up.